# Cant introspect Object with custom namespace

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, flash-builder

I have on loop introspecting objects and parsing them based on their properties.
It all works fine with normal objects. But I´m using some objects with a custom namespace and the same loop doesn't recognize any property and doesn't trace anything. The loop is pretty standard but I´m pasting here anyway:

```
for (var id:String in record) 
{
    trace(id, " : ", record[id]); 
}
```

anybody knows how to overcome this?
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I just found a solution.

It seems that cloning the object with bytearrays returns an Object with the default namespace.

the function follows:

```
function copy(value:Object):Object
{
    var buffer:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    buffer.writeObject(value);
    buffer.position = 0;
    var result:Object = buffer.readObject();
    return result;
}
```

I´ll leave it here if anyone have the same problem…

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler just to use describeType?

Comment: the loop I showed was just a striped down version. In the original loop was creating other objects based on the properties of the object I was introspecting.